# Исчезает выпадающий блок?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Всем привет сделал выпадающий блок. Весь код тут `http://jsfiddle.net/q6fnc34e/`. (первый раз использую этот ресурс. Код не выполняется почему то.) Использую вот этот код jquery.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.menu_href').hover(function(){
        $('.menu_vipad_1').show(200);

        },

        function(){

           $('.menu_vipad_1').hide(); 

        });


    });
```

При навидении на меню он показывается, но как только я хочу навести блок он исчезает. Нужно сделать по примеру http://www.spbmed.info/. Если навести на "Медучереждения" увидите выпадающий блок. Как сделать ребят? Или бросить все и сделать через CLICK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас скорее всего $('.menu_vipad_1') находится не в нутри $('.menu_href')

Comment: Так вот на сайте примере (http://www.spbmed.info/) там он тоже находится за пределами. Если он будет у меня находится в menu_href то у меня menu_vipad_1 не будет на всю ширину экрана.

Comment: Тогда вот так $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.menu_href').hover(function(){
        $('.menu_vipad_1').show(200);

    });
    
    $('.menu_vipad_1').hover(function(){
        

    }, function(){
     $(this).hide(200);
    });
    
    });

Comment: Обновил ваш пример http://jsfiddle.net/q6fnc34e/2/

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Почти получилось, остался небольшой маленький косяк. Обновил http://jsfiddle.net/q6fnc34e/3/. Если выбрать меню, потом перейти мышкой на выпадающий блок, а потом опять выбрать меню, то происходит опять анимация.